# setting file and directry permitions in django

Tags: django, file-permissions

Hi all i just set up nginx with my django project and want to set permission for the files and directries here is the permission i set and it dose not work what is the right one and what is best practice in django when it comes to file permission? also can I set it from nginx or just command line thanks

```
sudo find /home/my_home_dir/this_django_project/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644
sudo find /home/my_home_dir/this_django_project/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755
sudo chmod 700 /home/my_home_dir/this_django_project/./manage.py /home/my_home_dir/this_django_project/this_django_project/settings.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Practice:

1. Make sure none of your code is readable by nginx.
2. Make sure none of your static/media is writable by nginx.
3. Make sure media directory **is** writable by uwsgi/gunicorn.

Comment: Make sure it is writable by the same user that you run gunicorn with.